# how to keep files from style generator separated from other resources

Tags: android

I just used the [Android ActionBar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to generate theme for my actionBar. Instead of merging all the files into the folders of my existing project, I want to keep them separate. What is the best way to do this? have `res-actionbar` in addition to my existing `res` folder. Or have something like `drawable-actionbar`, `drawable-hdpi-actionbar`, etc. Or is this whole approach not even advisable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to do this?

Probably not to do it at all. They are your files. You are responsible for them. The fact that they were generated by that Web site, as opposed to being generated by an IDE's wizard, and as opposed to your typing them in, should be immaterial.

The only thing you can really do would be to put them in a separate Android library project, and that seems like overkill.

Admittedly, the site's use of a suffix rather than a prefix on filenames does make them a bit tough to organize. I have just filed [an enhancement request for a prefix option](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-actionbarstylegenerator/issues/96).

> have res-actionbar in addition to my existing res folder. Or have something like drawable-actionbar, drawable-hdpi-actionbar, etc.

Sorry, but you cannot invent new resource set qualifiers.